# Naive Fibonacci in C vs Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

Please, how to make the evaluation of `g` (fib) completely strict? (**I know that this exponential solution is not optimal.** I would like to know how to make that recursion **completely strict** /if possible/)

**Haskell**

```
g :: Int -> Int
g 0 = 0
g 1 = 1
g x = g(x-1) + g(x-2)
main = print $ g 42
```

So that it runs approximately as fast as the naive C solution:

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>

long f(int x)
{
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    if (x == 1) return 1;
    return f(x-1) + f(x-2);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%ld\n", f(42));
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: This fibs-recursion is used only as a supersimple example. I totally know, that there are dozens of better algorithms. But there definitely are recursive algorithms which DON'T HAVE so simple and more effective alternatives.

Comment: `g` is already strict (because it pattern matches on its only argument). Did you mean get it to use unboxed `Int`s?

Comment: @AndrewC Yes! That sounds more likely.

Comment: Hm, I don't get what your after, a Hello World that is completely strict so you can use the technique in another context? If so, your approved answer isn't really an answer to your question.

Comment: memoisation makes for a more effective recursive alternative.

Comment: "But there definitely are recursive algorithms which DON'T HAVE so simple and more effective alternatives." ... and which one of them was it you actually needed? Do you actually have a programming problem you're trying to solve? Something you're trying to achieve? Some real-world situation where you needed to speed up some haskell code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is, GHC makes the evaluation completely strict on its own (when you give it the chance by compiling with optimisations). The original code produces the core

```
Rec {
Main.$wg [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int#
[GblId, Arity=1, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType L]
Main.$wg =
  \ (ww_s1JE :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case ww_s1JE of ds_XsI {
      __DEFAULT ->
        case Main.$wg (GHC.Prim.-# ds_XsI 1) of ww1_s1JI { __DEFAULT ->
        case Main.$wg (GHC.Prim.-# ds_XsI 2) of ww2_X1K4 { __DEFAULT ->
        GHC.Prim.+# ww1_s1JI ww2_X1K4
        }
        };
      0 -> 0;
      1 -> 1
    }
end Rec }
```

which, as you can see if you know GHC's core, is completely strict and uses unboxed raw machine integers.

(Unfortunately, the machine code gcc produces from the C source is just plain faster.)

GHC's strictness analyser is rather good, and in simple cases like here, where there's no polymorphism involved and the function is not too complicated, you can count on it finding that it can unbox all values to produce a worker using unboxed `Int#`s.

However, in cases like this, there's more to producing fast code than just operating on machine types. The assembly produced by the native code generator, as well as by the LLVM backend is basically a direct translation of the code to assembly, check whether the argument is 0 or 1, and if not call the function twice and add the results. Both produce some entry and exit code I don't understand, and on my box, the native code generator produces the faster code.

For the C code, `clang -O3` produces the straightforward assembly with less cruft and using more registers,

```asm
.Ltmp8:
    .cfi_offset %r14, -24
    movl        %edi, %ebx
    xorl        %eax, %eax
    testl       %ebx, %ebx
    je          .LBB0_4
# BB#1:
    cmpl        $1, %ebx
    jne         .LBB0_3
# BB#2:
    movl        $1, %eax
    jmp         .LBB0_4
.LBB0_3:
    leal        -1(%rbx), %edi
    callq       recfib
    movq        %rax, %r14
    addl        $-2, %ebx
    movl        %ebx, %edi
    callq       recfib
    addq        %r14, %rax
.LBB0_4:
    popq        %rbx
    popq        %r14
    popq        %rbp
    ret
```

(which for some reason performs much better on my system today than it did yesterday). A lot of the difference in performance between the code produced from the Haskell source and the C comes from the use of registers in the latter case where indirect addressing is used in the former, the core of the algorithm is the same in both.

gcc, without any optimisations produces essentially the same using some indirect addressing, but less than what GHC produced with either the NCG or the LLVM backend. With `-O1`, ditto, but with even less indirect addressing. With `-O2`, you get a transformation so that the assembly doesn't easily map back to the source, and with `-O3`, gcc produces the fairly amazing

```asm
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r15
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 15, -16
    pushq   %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    .cfi_offset 14, -24
    pushq   %r13
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    .cfi_offset 13, -32
    pushq   %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    .cfi_offset 12, -40
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    .cfi_offset 6, -48
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 56
    .cfi_offset 3, -56
    subq    $120, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 176
    testl   %edi, %edi
    movl    %edi, 64(%rsp)
    movq    $0, 16(%rsp)
    je      .L2
    cmpl    $1, %edi
    movq    $1, 16(%rsp)
    je      .L2
    movl    %edi, %eax
    movq    $0, 16(%rsp)
    subl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, 108(%rsp)
.L3:
    movl    108(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 32(%rsp)
    testl   %eax, %eax
    movl    %eax, 72(%rsp)
    je      .L4
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    movq    $1, 32(%rsp)
    je      .L4
    movl    64(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 32(%rsp)
    subl    $2, %eax
    movl    %eax, 104(%rsp)
.L5:
    movl    104(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 24(%rsp)
    testl   %eax, %eax
    movl    %eax, 76(%rsp)
    je      .L6
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    movq    $1, 24(%rsp)
    je      .L6
    movl    72(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 24(%rsp)
    subl    $2, %eax
    movl    %eax, 92(%rsp)
.L7:
    movl    92(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 40(%rsp)
    testl   %eax, %eax
    movl    %eax, 84(%rsp)
    je      .L8
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    movq    $1, 40(%rsp)
    je      .L8
    movl    76(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 40(%rsp)
    subl    $2, %eax
    movl    %eax, 68(%rsp)
.L9:
    movl    68(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 48(%rsp)
    testl   %eax, %eax
    movl    %eax, 88(%rsp)
    je      .L10
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    movq    $1, 48(%rsp)
    je      .L10
    movl    84(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 48(%rsp)
    subl    $2, %eax
    movl    %eax, 100(%rsp)
.L11:
    movl    100(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 56(%rsp)
    testl   %eax, %eax
    movl    %eax, 96(%rsp)
    je      .L12
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    movq    $1, 56(%rsp)
    je      .L12
    movl    88(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 56(%rsp)
    subl    $2, %eax
    movl    %eax, 80(%rsp)
.L13:
    movl    80(%rsp), %eax
    movq    $0, 8(%rsp)
    testl   %eax, %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%rsp)
    je      .L14
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    movq    $1, 8(%rsp)
    je      .L14
    movl    96(%rsp), %r15d
    movq    $0, 8(%rsp)
    subl    $2, %r15d
.L15:
    xorl    %r14d, %r14d
    testl   %r15d, %r15d
    movl    %r15d, %r13d
    je      .L16
    cmpl    $1, %r15d
    movb    $1, %r14b
    je      .L16
    movl    4(%rsp), %r12d
    xorb    %r14b, %r14b
    subl    $2, %r12d
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L17:
    xorl    %ebp, %ebp
    testl   %r12d, %r12d
    movl    %r12d, %ebx
    je      .L18
    cmpl    $1, %r12d
    movb    $1, %bpl
    je      .L18
    xorb    %bpl, %bpl
    jmp     .L20
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L21:
    cmpl    $1, %ebx
    je      .L58
.L20:
    leal    -1(%rbx), %edi
    call    recfib
    addq    %rax, %rbp
    subl    $2, %ebx
    jne     .L21
.L18:
    addq    %rbp, %r14
    subl    $2, %r13d
    je      .L16
    subl    $2, %r12d
    cmpl    $1, %r13d
    jne     .L17
    addq    $1, %r14
.L16:
    addq    %r14, 8(%rsp)
    subl    $2, 4(%rsp)
    je      .L14
    subl    $2, %r15d
    cmpl    $1, 4(%rsp)
    jne     .L15
    addq    $1, 8(%rsp)
.L14:
    movq    8(%rsp), %rax
    addq    %rax, 56(%rsp)
    subl    $2, 96(%rsp)
    je      .L12
    subl    $2, 80(%rsp)
    cmpl    $1, 96(%rsp)
    jne     .L13
    addq    $1, 56(%rsp)
.L12:
    movq    56(%rsp), %rax
    addq    %rax, 48(%rsp)
    subl    $2, 88(%rsp)
    je      .L10
    subl    $2, 100(%rsp)
    cmpl    $1, 88(%rsp)
    jne     .L11
    addq    $1, 48(%rsp)
.L10:
    movq    48(%rsp), %rax
    addq    %rax, 40(%rsp)
    subl    $2, 84(%rsp)
    je      .L8
    subl    $2, 68(%rsp)
    cmpl    $1, 84(%rsp)
    jne     .L9
    addq    $1, 40(%rsp)
.L8:
    movq    40(%rsp), %rax
    addq    %rax, 24(%rsp)
    subl    $2, 76(%rsp)
    je      .L6
    subl    $2, 92(%rsp)
    cmpl    $1, 76(%rsp)
    jne     .L7
    addq    $1, 24(%rsp)
.L6:
    movq    24(%rsp), %rax
    addq    %rax, 32(%rsp)
    subl    $2, 72(%rsp)
    je      .L4
    subl    $2, 104(%rsp)
    cmpl    $1, 72(%rsp)
    jne     .L5
    addq    $1, 32(%rsp)
.L4:
    movq    32(%rsp), %rax
    addq    %rax, 16(%rsp)
    subl    $2, 64(%rsp)
    je      .L2
    subl    $2, 108(%rsp)
    cmpl    $1, 64(%rsp)
    jne     .L3
    addq    $1, 16(%rsp)
.L2:
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax
    addq    $120, %rsp
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 56
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    popq    %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    popq    %r13
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    popq    %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    popq    %r15
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L58:
    .cfi_restore_state
    addq    $1, %rbp
    jmp     .L18
    .cfi_endproc
```

which is much faster than anything else tested. gcc unrolled the algorithm to a remarkable depth, which neither GHC nor LLVM did, and that makes a huge difference here.

Comment: Oh, amazing. Well, how come that the Haskell solution is even with LLVM and `-O2` 2x slower than `C`?

Comment: If I knew that, it wouldn't be :/. As for GHC proper, that's just not the kind of code it's particularly good at, the effort is (still) more directed to higher-level optimisations, and there are too few people hacking on it to get to that kind of low-level transformations soon. As for LLVM, I suspect it's in part that one needs to pass the right options to its optimiser, and in part that GHC's output is not so idiomatic that LLVM really excels at optimising it in all cases.

Comment: I just found out that at least my version of clang is also much slower than gcc on the C code, so it's not just GHC.

Comment: Nice point, clang 3.0 is 34% slower than gcc 4.6.3 on my Mint 13 machine.

Comment: Oh, it's more here, 2.14s (clang 3.0) vs. 1.25s (gcc-4.6.2) on openSuSE 12.1 (64 bit).

Comment: Just wow... gcc must do some low level magic, the difference is huge.

Comment: Yes. gcc (-O3) produces some 240 lines of convoluted (and highly efficient) assembly (which I won't even try to follow) vs. about 40 from clang.

Comment: so @DanielFischer is the conclusion that the an old compiler produces faster exe, rather than C is faster than Haskell ? ;). AJA whats the lesson learned here?

Comment: @Jonke The conclusion is that operating on unboxed data isn't all that matters, and currently gcc's optimiser beats GHC's and clang's on this algorithm (and others, but not all). Not too surprising if you consider how many man-years have gone into building and improving each. Regarding "Language X is faster than Language Y", that's a badly posed question, it's always only implementations you can compare (though some languages make it easier to produce fast code than others - but that doesn't necessarily mean they're easier to transform into _very_ fast code), as you know.

Answer (score 4):

Start by using a better algorithm!

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

fib n = fibs !! n-1
```

`fib 42` will give you an answer much faster.

It's *much* more important to use a better algorithm than make minor speed tweaks.

You can happily and quickly calculate `fib 123456` in ghci (i.e. interpreted, not even compiled) with this definition (it's 25801 digits long). You might get your C code to calculate that faster, but you'll take quite a while writing it. This took me hardly any time at all. I spent much more time writing this post!

Morals:

1. Use the right algorithm!
2. Haskell lets you write clean versions of code, memoising answers simply.
3. It's sometimes easier to define an infinite list of answers and grab the one you want than to write some looping version that updates values.
4. Haskell is awesome.

Comment: Please, that was *NOT* the question. I know logarithmic solutions better than this. But would like to know, how to make this recursion strict.

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @Martin I am sorry, but the phrasing of your question misled me into thinking you were interested in the actual code you gave. You asked "Please, how to make the evaluation of g (fib) completely strict?" but it already was, and strictness is _NOT_ relevant to speeding up that code, and unboxing isn't much help either. You went on to say "So that it runs approximately as fast as the naive C solution", and I bet mine blows the C code out of the water. As you see I dealt with the question giving the best advice for someone with your stated problem. You added all the bold stuff later.

Comment: I up-voted your comment about unboxed data types (didn't know that), and removed the downvote from your answer.

Comment: And ABSOLUTELY agree... Haskell is awesome and everybody should always seek for the best algorithm possible ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that - cheered me up. Have fun. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is completely strict.

```
g :: Int -> Int
g 0 = 0
g 1 = 1
g x = a `seq` b `seq` a + b where
   a = g $! x-1
   b = g $! x-2
main = print $! g 42
```

`$!` is the same as `$` (low precedence function application) except that it is strict in the function argument.

You will want to compile with `-O2` as well, although I am curious as to why you don't want to use a better algorithm.

Comment: But you strictly evaluate `x`s, that is numbers from `42,41...,0`. Not the function values. Isn't that right?

Comment: Sorry, I realised that I'd only made it half strict while you were writing your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The function is already completely strict.

The usual definition of a function being strict is that if you give it undefined input, it will itself be undefined. I assume from context that you are thinking of a different notion of strictness, namely a function is strict if it evaluates its arguments before producing a result. But usually the only way to check if a value is undefined is to evaluate it, so the two are often equivalent.

According to the first definition, `g` is certainly strict, since it must check if the argument is equal to zero before knowing which branch of the definition to use, so if the argument is undefined, `g` itself will choke when it tries to read it.

According to a more informal definition, well, what could `g` do wrong? The first two clauses are obviously fine, and mean that by the time we get to the third clause, we must already have evaluated `n`. Now, in the third clause, we have an addition of two function calls. More completely, we have the following tasks:

1. subtract 1 from `n`
2. subtract 2 from `n`
3. call `g` with the result of 1.
4. call `g` with the result of 2.
5. add the results of 3. and 4. together.

Laziness can mess with the orders of these operations a little, but since both `+` and `g` need the values of their arguments before they can run their code, really nothing can be delayed by any significant amount, and certainly the compiler is free to run these operations in strict order if it can only show that `+` is strict (it's built-in, so that shouldn't be too hard) and `g` is strict (but it *obviously* is). So any reasonable optimising compiler will not have too much trouble with this, and furthermore any non-optimising compiler will not incur any significant overhead (it's certainly not like the situation of `foldl (+) 0 [1 .. 1000000]`) by doing the completely naive thing.

The lesson is that when a function immediately compares its argument against something, that function is already strict, and any decent compiler will be able to exploit that fact to eliminate the usual overheads of laziness. That does not mean it will be able to eliminate other overheads, like the time taken to start the runtime system, that tend to make Haskell programs a little slower than C programs. If you're just looking at performance numbers, there's a lot more going on there than whether your program is strict or lazy.